# Creating regexp pattern for grep

Tags: sed, grep, regular-expression

So I have a string like `LST = fr, de, pl, ru, ch, us, uk, ca`. Here I have to create a regex pattern for the future grep operation, so for that I have to modify my string to match like this `fr\|de\|pl\|ru\|ch\|us\|uk\|ca`

```
set LST = `grep "^LST *=" /remote/file/config.ini | sed 's/LST *= *//' | sed 's/ *//g' | tr , "\|"`
```

Unfortunately `tr , "\\|"` does not replace given characters to create my regexp pattern... the result is `frdeplruchusukca`. How do i create a regex pattern or how can I (for example) find occurance of `de` and set the found value to my LST variable ?

### config.ini sample

```
; sample of ini file
[SITE_PREF]

LST = fr, de, pl, ru, ch, us, uk, ca
TASKLIST = T1,TT3,TT0
```

Comment: So what does the input (in `config.ini`) look like, exactly?

Comment: @ilkkachu just a simple ini file with `[section]` and options, initial `LST` string is taken from that file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, first, `tr` works one character at a time, it can't replace a `,` with a `\|` (one to two characters). So instead, use `sed`: `sed -e 's/,/\\|/'`

Two, you can combine the `grep` and the `sed`s, this seems to work on Bash, with GNU sed:

```
$ LST=$(sed -n '/^LST *=/ {s/^LST *= *//; s/, */\\|/g; p}' config.ini)
$ echo "$LST"
fr\|de\|pl\|ru\|ch\|us\|uk\|ca
```

(That basically says: On all lines matching `/^LST *=/`, do the things in braces: two `s`ubstitutions and `p`rint the line.)

Three, with your `tr`, you should get the commas changed to backslashes or pipes, depending on if the quoting works or not, i.e.

```
$ echo "fr,de,pl" | tr , "\|" 
fr|de|pl
$ echo "fr,de,pl" | tr , '\\|'
fr\de\pl
```

But you didn't, you got nothing instead. I can't reproduce that with Bash, but that `set` syntax looks like `csh`, and I get some weird behaviour with `tcsh`. In some cases. Not all.

Ok:

```
$ tcsh
> echo "fr,de,pl" | sed 's/,/\\|/'
fr\|de,pl
> set LST = `echo "fr,de,pl" | sed 's/,/\\|/'`
> printf "%s\n" "$LST"
fr\|de,pl
```

Not so ok:

```
$ tcsh 
> echo "fr,de,pl" | sed 's/, */\\|/'
fr\|de,pl
> set LST = `echo "fr,de,pl" | sed 's/, */\\|/'`
> printf "%s\n" "$LST"
fr|de,pl
```

The only difference I can see, is the asterisk in the second case.

Comment: Don't use `echo` for checking backslash handling. Some `echo` implementations, including `tcsh`'s builtin one does do some processing of backslash sequences.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, point, though `\|` isn't a C-style escape, and while it prints a newline for `echo "\n"`, `echo "\|"` prints just `\|` without clobbering the backslash. And I get the same with `printf`. And `/bin/echo`. I can't see any sense in that behaviour, either that shell is crazy or I am.

Comment: (but `echo '\\'` outputs one backslash, so you would miss it if you put too much backslash) That shell is a mess (less so than csh but still is), Here, I guess the `*` tells `tcsh` somehow that there's a glob involved (even if in effect, there's none) and there's an extra layer of backslash handling for glob escaping.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
... | awk -F'= ' '{gsub(", ", "\\|", $2); print $2}'
```

- `-F '= '` sets field separator as `=`
- `gsub(", ", "\\|", $2)` substitute all `,` with `\|` in the second field in place
- `print $2` prints the second field

**Example:**

```
$ awk -F'= ' '{gsub(", ", "\\|", $2); print $2}' <<<'LST = fr, de, pl, ru, ch, us, uk, ca'
fr\|de\|pl\|ru\|ch\|us\|uk\|ca
```

Answer (score 1):

`fr\|de\|pl\|ru\|ch\|us\|uk\|ca` is not standard/portable as a regexp for grep, however:

```
fr
de
pl
ru
ch
us
uk
ca
```

That is with the items delimited with newline, is standard and can also be used with `grep -F` for fixed string search (so you don't have problems if your search terms contain regexp operators).

So you can do (here using POSIX shell syntax, you don't want to use `csh` for scripting):

```
search_term=$(
  sed '
    /^LST *= */!d
    s///
    s/ *, */\
/g' config.ini
)

grep -F -- "$search_term" some-file
```

If your `grep` implementation supports it, you can also pass the `-w` option to search for whole words only.

Answer (score 0):

`LST=$(grep "^LST *=" /remote/file/config.ini| sed -e 's/LST *= *//' -e 's/, */\\|/g')`

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -p0E '($_)= /LST = (.*)/; s/, /\\|/g' config.ini
```